# Does Pack Tactics work for a swallowed creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, racial-traits, kobold

Assume, a Giant Toad swallowed kobold A.
Kobold B stands near this Giant Toad (inside 5 feets).

Both kobolds have *Pack Tactics* feature, which says

> You have advantage on an attack roll against a creature if at least
>   one of your allies is within 5 feet of the creature and the ally isn’t
>   incapacitated.

Does it mean that both kobolds have advantage on an their attack rolls? Maybe only kobold A? Maybe only kobold B?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RAW then yes, advantage can be applied to *both* kobolds as all the requirements are met. The [giant toad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-toad)'s Swallow action doesn't impose the [incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) condition.

RAI, I would say no. The idea behind advantage through Pack Tactics or flanking is that your ally is in a position to distract the enemy, thus making your attack more likely to be successful. When one of the allies is swallowed inside the enemy, I would say its ability to distract is severely limited.

So, it is GM-dependent, I would say. There are arguments that could be made for either ruling.

Comment: One such argument is that the kobolds cannot see each other making it impossible to coordinate their attacks.

Comment: I disagree to some extent. Foob that doesn't agree with you can be very distracting.

Comment: "When one of the allies is swallowed inside the enemy I would say its ability to distract is severely limited." I disagree : acid refluxes can already be mildly disruptive, imagine a kobold poking your intestines from inside...

Comment: Relevant meta: [Please avoid using the RAI acronym, or use it carefully & be clear in context](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/please-avoid-using-the-rai-acronym-or-use-it-carefully-be-clear-in-context). You should expand the acronym or rephrase it to be clear.